# Protractor Wait Fails Unnecessarily

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, protractor

I'm trying to write a Protractor E2E test that checks if a certain element is present through `browser.wait(...)` with `element1.isPresent()`, and if it is, then good, but otherwise I want to check that another element is present via `element2.isPresent()`.

Exactly one of `element1` and `element2` should be present, and if neither are, then I want the test to fail.

My code looks like this:

```
var element1 = element(by.id('test-elem1'));
var element2 = element(by.id('test-elem2'));
browser.wait(function() {
    return element1.isPresent();
}, 5000, "Waiting for element 1").then(function() {
    console.log('Found element 1');
    // Do something with element 1
}, function() {
    // Element 1 not present --> look for element 2
    browser.wait(function() {
        return element2.isPresent();
    }, 5000, "Waiting for element 2");
    print('Found element 2');
});
```

What I would expect is:

- if `element1` is present, then the first `browser.wait` will finish with a succeeded promise, so its `.then` should go into the first function, and print `Found element 1`.
- If `element1` is, however, not present, then the first `browser.wait` will finish with a failed promise, so the `.then` should go into the second function, which looks for `element2`. Then, if `element2` is present, the test should continue, print `Found element 2`, and then pass. If `element2` is not present, however, it should fail at this second `browser.wait` and thus the test should fail.

What actually happens is that if `element1` is not present, the first `browser.wait` just fails and makes the test fail. If `element1` is present, then the rest of the test continues as expected.

I was under the impression that if the second parameter to `.then()` is defined, then on fail, that second function should be called, rather than failing completely.

I'm pretty sure that I had code that was almost the same working elsewhere (I since deleted it, so I can't reference it anymore), so I'm not sure why this part is not working.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the Expected Conditions, there is a [built-in `or` operator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.or):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var element1 = element(by.id('test-elem1'));
var element2 = element(by.id('test-elem2'));

browser.wait(EC.or(EC.presenceOf(element1), EC.presenceOf(element2)), 5000);
```

This would fail if both elements are not present and pass otherwise.

---

Now, let's try to understand what is happening with your initial code.

The first problem is that the first argument to [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) should be a function. Also, you should put the second `console.log()` call into the `then()` callback of the second `browser.wait()` call:

```
var element1 = element(by.id('test-elem1'));
var element2 = element(by.id('test-elem2'));

browser.wait(function() {
    return element1.isPresent();
}, 5000).then(function() {
    console.log('Found element 1');
}, function() {
    // Element 1 not present --> look for element 2
    browser.wait(function() {
        return element2.isPresent();
    }, 5000).then(function () {
        print('Found element 2');
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh, oops. I left the first argument to `browser.wait` as a string because I was using a wrapper for it that actually took a string first. I forgot to remove it when writing my question.

Comment: Also, I need to do different things depending on whether I find `element1` or `element2`. Should I still use expected conditions for that?

Comment: @Jashaszun well, you can still use them to wait, but then additionally issue `isPresent()` checks. Or, you can stick to the current approach (assuming it works now)..btw, you can replace the functions with `EC.presenceOf` calls. Thanks.

Comment: I'm now trying your approach. I check whether either exists with `EC.or(..., ...)`, and then afterwards I do a check on `element1.isPresent()` with `.then(function(present) { if (present) { /* element 1 present */ } else { /* element 2 present */ } });` However, it always seems to think that element 1 is present. Any ideas on this? No problem if the answer is "put that in its own question."

Comment: @Jashaszun interesting. Are you sure the `element1` actually is not present on the page? (may be it is present but not displayed, for example?)

Comment: I just realized that I was using `isPresent` instead of `isDisplayed`, when both are present, but only one is displayed... so it was a dumb question. (Doesn't invalidate the original question, at least :) )

Comment: @Jashaszun well, that's okay, it's quite a common mistake. Let me know if there is anything else I can help you with in this topic. Thanks